# BotMethodInvalidError occurs however i use a personal telegram account

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I run this:

```
async def main():
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        print(dialog.name, 'has ID', dialog.id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

And it causes BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetDialogsRequest).
But i didn't use a bot, i used a personal telegram account.

Comment: What is `client`, and how is it defined?  What is the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: The client is defined in this way:                                                                 
api_id_user = 12345678
api_hash_user = "3123123ljklkjlkjlkjljk"

client = TelegramClient('danya', api_id=api_id_user, api_hash=api_hash_user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

if you're certain you used a personal account and no bot_token, this means there is garbage .session file from previous bot login.. change the name and login once again with phone number, the danya2.session will be the user session to use, danya seems to be a bot.

```py
TelegramClient('danya2', api_id=api_id_user, api_hash=api_hash_user)
```

You can check the current account logged-in in `client` using [`client.get_me()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_me)

---

Only users can [get the open dialogs](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_dialogs.html) in the account, logins with bot token aren't allowed to do that through the Telegram api.

a bot has to only handle realtime resources in events and cache them for future usage.

Comment: I didn't use the bot, i used a personal telegram account

Comment: see the edited part